# Why I'm getting FastAPI int parsing Error?

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm trying to delete tag from the image with this API:

Those are my tagged images:

```json
{
  "url": "http://localhost:8000/tags/images",
  "duration": 0.002218008041381836,
  "response": {
    "images": [
      {
        "tag_id": 1,
        "file_path": "datasets/environmental/0001/000000.jpg",
        "image_hash": "837a665df2e743f67805b74d8e504fd382d82490a8e9a09e8aad17d2020f1539",
        "user_who_created": "sandro",
        "creation_time": "2024-01-11T20:01:49.363408"
      },
      {
        "tag_id": 1,
        "file_path": "datasets/environmental/0001/000001.jpg",
        "image_hash": "cf7af99247760c7b9d8289e4da0e1c12be87e6bc1d0a4cf37455e0b06fe5ea71",
        "user_who_created": "sandro",
        "creation_time": "2024-01-11T20:02:09.597206"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and with this API, I'm trying to delete tagged image with `image_hash` and `tag_id`:

```py
@router.delete("/tags/remove_tag_from_image")
def remove_image_tag(
    request: Request,
    image_hash: str,  
    tag_id: int,
):

    # The query now checks for the specific tag_id within the array of tags
    query = {"image_hash": image_hash, "tag_id": tag_id}

    # Attempt to delete the document
    result = request.app.image_tags_collection.delete_one(query)

    # If no document was found and deleted, raise an HTTPException
    if result.deleted_count == 0:
        print("Tag or image hash not found!")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Tag or image hash not found")

    return {"status": "success"}
```

I'm running curl command like that:

```
curl -X 'DELETE' \
  'http://localhost:8000/tags/remove_tag_from_image?image_hash=837a665df2e743f67805b74d8e504fd382d82490a8e9a09e8aad17d2020f1539&tag_id=1' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```

but every time I'm getting error like this:

> **Validation Error: [{'type': 'int_parsing', 'loc': ('path', 'tag_id'), 'msg': 'Input should be a valid integer, unable to parse string as an integer', 'input': 'remove_tag_from_image', 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/int_parsing'}]**

I tried to use tag_id as query parameter like `that tag_id: int = Query(...)`, but still same problem. I just can't figure out why fastapi parsing integer as string.

Python 3.11.3

Name: fastapi
Version: 0.101.1

Comment: Using the code above, I wasn't able to recreate this error. Please include a complete minimum viable example to recreate the error, including imports, setup of the router, and which Python and FastAPI versions you're using. To help debug, I'd suggest removing all unrelated code from the example, such as `result = request.app.image_tags_collection.delete_one(query)`, to narrow down the source of the problem.

Comment: The problem is that another route is registered with `/tags/{tag_id}`, and this is defined as `tag_id` being an int. This route gets matched when you're calling `/tags/remove_tag_from_image`, and `remove_tag_from_image` is not an integer. This is why it works in your isolated example, but not when you're using it in your project. So the code you've included is not the code complaining about the problem. To fix this, register the endpoint you've included first, then register the other endpoint.